# Do you use google protocol buffers only in datagram mode?

Tags: protocol-buffers

If I have a definition which is only repeated strings, I can find the length of the packed buffers via the get_packed_size call.  However, if I am on the receiving side of the exchange, how do I know how many bytes to read to form a complete message?  (Since there are a variable number of entries, it isn't known apriori.)

Sender:

```
length = <name>_get_packed_size(&message)
buffer = malloc(length)
<name>_pack(&message, buffer)
write(fd, buffer, length)
```

Receiver:

```
read(fd, buffer, ???)       // what is '???' if 'fd' is a stream socket?
```

If I am in datagram mode, I can issue the read for something like 64K bytes and just get the entire message.  However, if I am in stream mode, how do I do this without short changing the message or reading part of the next message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer for a typical solution to this common problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5586945/618259