# Protobuf, CodedInputStream parsing partial messages

Tags: c++, boost-asio, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to implement protobuf sending/receiving that's compatible with the java version, which includes a varint32-prefix first.

I've almost got it working, but for some reason some messages become partial and fail an assert().

```
/receiver.cpp:69: void tcp_connection::handle_read_message(const boost::system::error_code&, size_t): Assertion `line.ParseFromCodedStream(&input)' failed.
```

semder.pp

```
boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
std::ostream writer(&buffer);
bool packet_full = false;
uint32_t sent_lines = 0;
{ //new scope for protobuf streams, these flush in dtor
    google::protobuf::io::OstreamOutputStream osostream(&writer);
    google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream output(&osostream);
    std::string lines;
    while(std::getline(reader, line)) {
        lines += line + "\n";
        ++sent_lines;
        if(sent_lines > 100) {
            packet_full = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!lines.empty()) {
        msg->set_text(lines);
        const uint32_t size = msg->ByteSize();
        output.WriteVarint32(size);
        uint8_t* buffer = output.GetDirectBufferForNBytesAndAdvance(size);
        if(buffer != 0) {
            msg->SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(buffer);
        } else {
            msg->SerializeWithCachedSizes(&output);
        }
}
if(sent_lines > 0) {
    sock.send(buffer.data());
    if(!packet_full && !reader.eof()) { //Read ended, and not due to end of file
        std::cout << "An error occured" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    reader.clear(); //clear EOF flag
}
```

receiver.cpp

It's a boost asio callback.

Member variables:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
boost::asio::streambuf buffer_;
```

Code

```
void handle_read_message(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                      size_t bytes_transferred) {


   if(!error) {
      buffer_.commit(bytes_transferred);
      std::istream reader(&buffer_);
      google::protobuf::io::IstreamInputStream isistream(&reader);
      google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream input(&isistream);
      uint32_t size = 0;
      assert(input.ReadVarint32(&size));
      auto limit = input.PushLimit(size);
      msgs::Line line;
      assert(line.ParseFromCodedStream(&input));
      assert(input.ConsumedEntireMessage());
      input.PopLimit(limit);

      start();  
    } else {
      std::cout <<"error during handle_read_message: " << error << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This is mainly based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/22899712

EDIT:
New receiver version, reader_ is now a member variable:

```
void handle_read_message(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                          size_t bytes_transferred) {
    std::cout << "handle_read_message(" << bytes_transferred << ")" <<std::endl;
    if(!error) {
      buffer_.commit(bytes_transferred);
      uint32_t size = 0;
      google::protobuf::io::IstreamInputStream isistream_(&reader_);
      {
        google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream input(&isistream_);
        if(!input.ReadVarint32(&size)) {
          std::cout << "Failed to read size, waiting for more data" << std::endl;
          start();
          return;
        }
      }
      std::size_t varint_size = isistream_.ByteCount();
      std::cout <<"varintsize: " << varint_size << ", size: " << size << ", have bytes: " << buffer_.size() << std::endl;
      if(varint_size + size > buffer_.size()) {
        std::cout << "Not enough data received, waiting for more" << std::endl;
        start();
        return;
      }
      google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream input(&isistream_);
      auto limit = input.PushLimit(size);
      msgs::Line line;
      assert(line.ParseFromCodedStream(&input));
      std::cout << line.text() << std::endl;
      assert(input.ConsumedEntireMessage());
      input.PopLimit(limit);

      start();  
    } else {
      std::cout <<"error during handle_read_message: " << error << std::endl;
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using async I/O on the receiving end, you will need to ensure that you have really received the entire message before you start parsing. Remember that a TCP connection is a stream. The async callback runs any time there is data available -- even if it is incomplete. You may get only a partial message, or you may get a whole message plus some of the next message. This is why `readDelimitedFrom()` is needed in the first place: to figure out exactly how many bytes you need to wait for before parsing.

So, when using async I/O, you'll need to code things differently. You could use a strategy like this:

- Maintain a buffer containing all the bytes you've received so far.
- Each time you receive more bytes, add them to the buffer. Then, start trying to parse them as follows -- you must always start from scratch, with a brand-new `ZeroCopyInputStream` and `CodedInputStream`.
- Then, try using `ReadVarint32()` to read the size. If ReadVarint32 fails, then you haven't received the whole size yet, so stop and wait for more bytes.
- If `ReadVarint32()` succeeds, destroy the `CodedInputStream` and then call `ByteCount()` on the underlying `ZeroCopyInputStream` to find out how many bytes were consumed by the varint.
- You now know the size of the message and the size of the varint prefix. Add those together. If you have fewer than this many bytes in your buffer, stop and wait for more.
- You now have all the bytes of your message. Go ahead and pull them out of the buffer and parse them. Note that if you have more bytes in your buffer than the size of the message, you should leave the extra bytes in the buffer as they are part of the next message.

(Also: There seems to be a missing closing brace in your sender.cpp code. If the original file has the same error, it may be that you're sending data before CodedOutputStream has flushed. But I'm guessing the error is not in the original.)

Comment: Thanks for the well written answer, I've put up a new version that I think covers your points. Could you look through it? I still get assert crashes on ParseFromCodedStream.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see an obvious problem. I recommend dumping the raw bytes on both ends and comparing. I.e. use `SerializeAsString()` on the sending end, print a hex version of the bytes it produces, then on the receiving end print a hex version of the content of the buffer just before you parse it. If they aren't identical, then something went wrong in transit and you can start narrowing it down.