# Cannot deserialize protobuf data from C++ in Java

Tags: java, c++, protocol-buffers

My problem is to serialize protobuf data in C++ and deserialize the data in Java probably. 
Here is the code I use to the hints given by dcn:

With this I create the protobuf data in C++ and write it to an ostream which is send via socket.

```
Name name;
name.set_name("platzhirsch");

boost::asio::streambuf b;
std::ostream os(&b);

ZeroCopyOutputStream *raw_output = new OstreamOutputStream(&os);
CodedOutputStream *coded_output = new CodedOutputStream(raw_output);

coded_output->WriteLittleEndian32(name.ByteSize());
name.SerializeToCodedStream(coded_output);
socket.send(b);
```

This is the Java side where I try to parse it:

```
NameProtos.Name name = NameProtos.Name.parseDelimitedFrom(socket.getInputStream());
System.out.println(name.newBuilder().build().toString());
```

However by this I get this Exception:
**com.google.protobuf.UninitializedMessageException: Message missing required fields: name**

What am I missing?

---

The flawed code line is: `name.newBuilder().build().toString()`

This would have never worked, a new instance is created with uninitialized name field. Anyway the answer here solved the rest of my problem.

One last thing, which I was told in the protobuf mailinglist: In order to flush the CodedOutputStreams, the objects have to be deleted!

```
delete coded_output;
delete raw_output;
```

Comment: what does your code look like which fills the received array?

Comment: Try printing out the result of "message.SerializeAsString()" and of "received" and see if they're the same.

Comment: @jtahlborn I described it in my updated question. Please have a look.

Comment: @Kannan-Goundan They are. Please see also my modified question.

Comment: It's not a \0 (end-of-string) marker?

Comment: I do know nothing about protocol buffers, but are you sure that `SerializeAsString` and `toString` are the right methods here? Isn't there some binary serialization method?

Comment: java and network byte order are big endian.  seems a little odd that you are using little endian.

Comment: @jtahlborn There is no WriteBigEndian32 function defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what `received` is in your Java code, but your problem may be due to some charset conversion. Note also that protobuf does not delimit the messages when serializing.

Therefore you should use *raw data* to transmit the messages (byte array or directly (de)serialize from/to streams). 
If you intent to send many message you should also send the size before you send the actual messages.

In Java you can do it directly via `parseDelimitedFrom(InputStream)` and `writeDelimitedTo(OutputStream)`. You can do the same in C++ a litte more complex using `CodedOutputStream` like

```
codedOutput.WriteVarint32(protoMessage.ByteSize());
protoMessage.SerializeToCodedStream(&codedOutput);
```

See also [this ealier thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340730/are-there-c-equivalents-for-the-protocol-buffers-delimited-i-o-functions-in-jav)

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Currently I serialize to std::ostream and send this via socket. name.SerializeToOStream(&os); and in Java I read it like this: NameProtos.Name.parseDelimitedFrom(socket.getInputStream()); but I guess it will not work without using CodeOutputStream?

Comment: `parseDelimitedFrom` expects to read the size first, and I think `SerializeToOStream` does not write the size. If you only send a single message this is no problem (use `parseFrom` instead in this case). Otherwise you have to transmit the size too.

Comment: This is great, I have the feeling I am on the right way, however I still get exceptions on the Java side? Could you be so kind and look at the attachment I edited to my original question at the end? This is the code I am using currently, I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing two things to the stream, a size and the `Name` object, but only trying to read one.

As a general question: why do you feel the need to use CodedInputStream? To quote the [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.coded_stream.html):

> Typically these classes will only be
>   used internally by the protocol buffer
>   library in order to encode and decode
>   protocol buffers. Clients of the
>   library only need to know about this
>   class if they wish to write custom
>   message parsing or serialization
>   procedures

And to emphasize *jtahlborn*'s comment: why little-endian? Java deals with big-endian values, so will have to convert on reading.

Comment: This is what I am doing. I use protobuf for inter-process communication which means, I use it was messaging service. Further, I agree on the endian issue, but I cannot find API docs how to use alternative methods.

Comment: @platzhirsch - not sure what that comment means. However, if you write two things to the stream, you need to read two things. And the code that you posted only reads one thing.