# Writing Delimited C++ Protobuf Messages and Reading in Java

Tags: java, c++, protocol-buffers

I am writing multiple protobuf messages to a file in C++.

```
int fifoPipe = open("/media/my_pipe", O_WRONLY);

MyModel *model = new MyModel();

// Write to fifo pipe.
model->SerializeToFileDescriptor(fifoPipe);
```

I had read that the message size is written to the file automatically before the message data.  Apparently this is not the case:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques?hl=en

So in Java it should be possible to read the message like so:

```
MyModel.parseDelimitedFrom(fileInputStream);
```

However there are questions here:

[Cannot deserialize protobuf data from C++ in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670765/cannot-deserialize-protobuf-data-from-c-in-java)

[Are there C++ equivalents for the Protocol Buffers delimited I/O functions in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340730/are-there-c-equivalents-for-the-protocol-buffers-delimited-i-o-functions-in-ja)

That say the message size must be written manually.

Since the questions are kind of old this procedure may have changed.

**What is the proper way of writing multiple messages in C++ and reading those messages in Java?**

Also consider how Java would respond to a half written message.  In theory it should wait for data the size of message size to be present before returning.

Comment: As I read it, the C++ code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340730/are-there-c-equivalents-for-the-protocol-buffers-delimited-i-o-functions-in-ja will write the lengths expected by the Java method parseDelimitedFrom.

Comment: @JesperSM Same interpretation here. tzaman's answer indicates Java implements it yet C++ does not.  With all the resources google has one has to wonder why things are like this.

Comment: True, but then again code is written by individuals, not companies, especially open source. At least Kenton Varda was nice enough to post a useful implementation. You won't be the first to copy and paste a few lines of code from Stackoverflow in order to get the job done... ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the `parseDelimitedFrom()` and `writeDelimitedTo()` methods still have not been added to the C++ library.

The code I wrote in the answer to one of the questions you referenced is still the best way to implement this in C++:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22927149/2686899

The main reason why Google with all its resources hasn't gotten around to adding these in C++ is because Google internally does not use this format at all. For network communications, Google uses its internal RPC protocol (very similar to [GRPC](http://www.grpc.io/), which they open sourced recently), and for storing messages to disk they usually a variety of internal formats that are a bit more featureful than this "delimited" format (you might consider using sqlite, for example).

In fact, when Protobuf was first open sourced, `parseDelimitedFrom()` didn't exist even in Java. I added it later specifically as a stopgap for users of the open source library -- a lot of people asked us how to write multiple messages to a file, and telling them "you should develop your own framing library" didn't seem very nice.

Google may be a huge company, but at that time I was the *only* person working full-time on Protocol Buffers. Unfortunately, for reasons that I don't quite remember, I only implemented the functions in Java, and never got around to adding them in C++ as well. In retrospect it seems a bit silly -- writing C++ code wouldn't have been very hard, as you can see at the link above. But I had a lot to do, as you might imagine.

The current Protobuf team took over in 2010, and I moved on to other things (and eventually left Google). I don't know for sure why they haven't added this code to the C++ library, but my guess is that not enough people have asked for it and they are focused on other things. I bet if you file a bug, and link to my code -- or better yet, submit a pull request yourself -- they might just take it. (I would submit a pull request myself, but right now I don't have time to write the necessary unit tests, etc...)

**EDIT:** OK, against my better judgment I took the time to prepare a pull request: https://github.com/google/protobuf/pull/710