# Google Protocol Buffers - Storing messages into file

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm using google protocol buffer to serialize equity market data (ie. timestamp, bid,ask fields).
I can store one message into a file and deserialize it without issue.

How can I store multiple messages into a single file? Not sure how I can separate the messages. I need to be able to append new messages to the file on the fly.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: reading would not work without delimiters if you write more than 1 top level message in a file/stream. See accepted answer from Marc Gravell and https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#streaming

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I would recommend using the `writeDelimitedTo(OutputStream)` and `parseDelimitedFrom(InputStream)` methods on `Message` objects. `writeDelimitedTo` writes the length of the message before the message itself; `parseDelimitedFrom` then uses that length to read only one message and no farther. This allows multiple messages to be written to a single `OutputStream` to then be parsed separately. For more information, see https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageLite#writeDelimitedTo(java.io.OutputStream)

Comment: I'm not sure---I'm pretty new to the protobuf world myself.

Comment: Do they have an equivalent in C++?

Comment: Looks like this has always been there (in the Java implementation at least).  It's in this rev from 2009: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageLite.java?spec=svn163&r=163

Comment: @AndrewHundt The C++ equivalent is provided by the author of the Protobuf C++ library in this [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22927149/757777)

Answer (score 14):

From the docs:

http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/techniques.html#streaming

> Streaming Multiple Messages
>
> If you want to write multiple messages to a single file or stream, it
>   is up to you to keep track of where one message ends and the next
>   begins. The Protocol Buffer wire format is not self-delimiting, so
>   protocol buffer parsers cannot determine where a message ends on their
>   own. The easiest way to solve this problem is to write the size of
>   each message before you write the message itself. When you read the
>   messages back in, you read the size, then read the bytes into a
>   separate buffer, then parse from that buffer. (If you want to avoid
>   copying bytes to a separate buffer, check out the CodedInputStream
>   class (in both C++ and Java) which can be told to limit reads to a
>   certain number of bytes.)

Answer (score 6):

Protobuf does not include a terminator per outermost record, so you need to do that yourself. The simplest approach is to prefix the data with the length of the record that follows. Personally, I tend to use the approach of writing a string-header (for an arbitrary field number), then the length as a "varint" - this means the entire document is then itself a valid protobuf, and could be consumed as an object with a "repeated" element, however, just a fixed-length (typically 32-bit little-endian) marker would do just as well. With any such storage, it is appendable as you require.

Comment: After all this I found that CSV ended up being smaller! Probably because most of the time my numbers fit into single characters.

Comment: Hi Marc, can you elaborate on the 'string-header' idea ?

Comment: @AntonioD by "string-header", I mean the "length-delimited" encoding (wire-type 2), as used by strings and other sub-data. Basically: pick your arbitrary field-number, left-shift it by 3, "or" it with 2 (the wire-type), and varint-encode the result (this is the standard process for representing a field-header in protobuf). So if your arbitrary field is `1`, you just prepend with 10 / 0x0A.

Comment: @Perrot not really, no - I'm not a Java person

Comment: I was in the process of writing an example to replace my comment. And you replied at that moment ;)

Comment: To write several protobuf messages to a stream/file, wrap your output stream into a CodedOutputStream `CodedOutputStream writer = CodedOutputStream.newInstance(outputStreamToWrite); writer.writeRawVarint32(bytes.length); writer.writeRawBytes(bytes);`
To read the entire file: `CodedInputStream is = CodedInputStream.newInstance(inputStreamToWrap); while (!is.isAtEnd()) {int size = is.readRawVarint32(); YourMessage.parseFrom(is.readRawBytes(size);}`

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for a C++ solution, Kenton Varda [submitted a patch to protobuf around August 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340730/are-there-c-equivalents-for-the-protocol-buffers-delimited-i-o-functions-in-ja/22927149#22927149) that adds support for writeDelimitedTo() and readDelimitedFrom() calls that will serialize/deserialize a sequence of proto messages to/from a file in a way that's compatible with the Java version of these calls. Unfortunately this patch hasn't been approved yet, so if you want the functionality you'll need to merge it yourself.

Another option is Google has open sourced protobuf file reading/writing code through other projects. The [or-tools](https://github.com/google/or-tools) library, for example, contains the classes [RecordReader](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/base/recordio/RecordReader/) and [RecordWriter](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/base/recordio/RecordWriter/) that serialize/deserialize a proto stream to a file.

If you would like stand-alone versions of these classes that have almost no external dependencies, I have a fork of or-tools that contains only these classes. See: https://github.com/moof2k/recordio

Reading and writing with these classes is straightforward:

```
File* file = File::Open("proto.log", "w");
RecordWriter writer(file);
writer.WriteProtocolMessage(msg1);
writer.WriteProtocolMessage(msg2);
...
writer.Close();
```

Answer (score -8):

An easier way is to base64 encode each message and store it as a record per line.

Comment: The overhead of encoding/decoding base64 may defeat the purpose of protobuf being fast and small.