# How to fully read a file with delimited messages in Google Protobufs?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, delimited

I'm trying to read a file, which has multiple delimited messages in it (in the thousands), how can I do this **properly** using Google protobufs?

This is how I'm writing the delimited:

```
MyMessage myMessage = MyMessage.parseFrom(byte[] msg);
myMessage.writeDelimitedTo(FileOutputStream);
```

and this is how I'm reading the delimited file;

```
    CodedInputStream is = CodedInputStream.newInstance(new FileInputStream("/location/to/file"));

    while (!is.isAtEnd()) {
        int size = is.readRawVarint32(); 
        MyMessage msg = MyMessage.parseFrom(is.readRawBytes(size));
    //do stuff with your messages
    }
```

I'm kind of confused because the accepted answer in this question say's to use .parseDelimitedFrom() to read the delimited bytes; [Google Protocol Buffers - Storing messages into file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148878/google-protocol-buffers-storing-messages-into-file/14991815#14991815)

However, when using .parseDelimitedFrom(), it only reads the first message. (I don't know how to read the whole file using parseDelimitedFrom()).

This comment say's to write the delimited messages using CodedOutputStream: [Google Protocol Buffers - Storing messages into file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148878/google-protocol-buffers-storing-messages-into-file#comment20003485_9150005) (i.e. writer.writeRawVariant()). I'm currently using the implementation of this comment to read the whole file. Does writeDelimitedTo() basically do the same thing as

```
writer.writeRawVarint32(bytes.length);
```

and

```
 writer.writeRawBytes(bytes);
```

Also, if my way isn't the proper way of reading a whole file consisting of delimited messages, can you please show me what is?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `writeDelimitedTo()` simply writes the length as a varint followed byte the bytes. There's no need to use `CodedOutputStream` directly if you're working in Java.

`parseDelimitedFrom()` parses one message, but you may call it repeatedly to parse all the messages in the `InputStream`. The method will return `null` when you reach the end of the stream.