# protobuf: Serializing delimited message to coded stream fails after 8192 bytes

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am attempting to write a series of messages [delimited using this function](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/util/delimited_message_util.cc#L96) in `google::protobuf::util` to a coded stream pointed to a file on my local filesystem. It appears that the call to `message.SerializeWithCachedSizes()` is failing after successfully writing exactly 8192 bytes of delimited messages to the stream.

My use case is almost identical to this user who [asked a question about how to write  messages to a file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148878/google-protocol-buffers-storing-messages-into-file)

The protocol buffer documentation does not say anything about special handling of writing data to a coded stream beyond 8192 bytes as far as I could see, so I would assume this should just work. Is this expected behavior and have others used this function successfully without issue?

I have also tried using Ostream and ZeroCopyFileStream as well with the same behavior.