# Google::protobuf + boost::asio failure

Tags: c++, linux, boost-asio, protocol-buffers

I have studied the existing examples:

1. [Sending Protobuf Messages with boost::asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810026/sending-protobuf-messages-with-boostasio)
2. [Reading Protobuf objects using boost::asio::read_async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954392/reading-protobuf-objects-using-boostasioread-async)
3. [Google Protocol Buffers: parseDelimitedFrom and writeDelimitedTo for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269452/google-protocol-buffers-parsedelimitedfrom-and-writedelimitedto-for-c)
4. [Are there C++ equivalents for the Protocol Buffers delimited I/O functions in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340730/are-there-c-equivalents-for-the-protocol-buffers-delimited-i-o-functions-in-ja)
5. [Sending Protobuf Messages with boost::asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810026/sending-protobuf-messages-with-boostasio)

but I still can not figure out how to pass Google Protobuf messages using the Boost::asio API. In particular I have no clear understanding of the following problems:

1. Interaction between boost::asio::streambuf and google::protobuf::io objects (and the necessity of the applying of the last ones)
2. Correct implementation of the message streaming (due to the lack of writeDelimitedTo and parseDelimitedFrom methods in C++ API)

Here is my implementation based on boost::asio v. 1.39 ssl_client from [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp).

```
    class client
{
public:
  client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, boost::asio::ssl::context& context,
      boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
    : socket_(io_service, context),
        request_stream(&b),
        raw_output(&request_stream),
        coded_output(&raw_output)
  {
    ... 
  }

  void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
  {
    ...
  }

  //Debugging function
  void print_buffers_condition(const char *step)
  {
      std::cout << "\nBuffer conditions after " << step << std::endl;
      std::cout << "boost::asio::streambuf\t\tb: " << b.size() << std::endl;
      std::cout << "google::protobuf::io::OstreamOutputStream raw_output: " << raw_output.ByteCount() << std::endl;
      std::cout << "google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream coded_output: " << coded_output.ByteCount() << std::endl;
      std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  //Sending test message after SSL Handshake
  void handle_handshake(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
      std::cout << "-----------------------------SENDING-----------------------------" << std::endl;
    print_buffers_condition("handle handshake");
    if (!error)
    {
        SearchRequest msg;
        msg.set_query("qwerty");
        msg.set_code(12345);

        std::cout << "Debugged" << std::endl;
        msg.PrintDebugString();


        //Writing the length of the message before and serializing                 
                    print_buffers_condition("before serialising");
        coded_output.WriteVarint32(msg.ByteSize());
        if (!msg.SerializeToCodedStream(&coded_output))
        {
            std::cout << "serailizing error" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "serializing success" << std::endl;
        }

        //Sending
        buffers_condition("before async write");
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                                 b,
                                 boost::bind(&client::handle_write, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        buffers_condition("after async write");
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "Handshake failed: " << error << "\n";
    }
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    std::cout << " bytes_trransferred: " << bytes_transferred << std::endl;
    if (!error)
    {
        std::cout << "No error" << std::endl;
        ...
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "Write failed: " << error << "\n";
    }
  }

  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    ...
  }

private:
  boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_;
  boost::asio::streambuf b;
  std::ostream request_stream;
  google::protobuf::io::OstreamOutputStream raw_output;
  google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream coded_output;
};
```

This code is operational, so after creating the message we fall into the `void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)` function. Printing the `bytes_transferred_` value returns 0: server (implemented on the base of [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/server.cpp) too) recieves nothing.

The usage of the debugging function `void print_buffers_condition(const char *step)` hints at loss of message during its transmission through a stack of different buffering objects:

```
    $ ./client 127.0.0.1 5000
-----------------------------SENDING-----------------------------

Buffer conditions after handle handshake
boost::asio::streambuf      b: 0
google::protobuf::io::OstreamOutputStream raw_output: 8192
google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream coded_output: 0

Debugged: 
query: "qwerty"
code: 12345

Buffer conditions after before serialization
boost::asio::streambuf      b: 0
google::protobuf::io::OstreamOutputStream raw_output: 8192
google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream coded_output: 0

serializing success

Buffer conditions after before async write
boost::asio::streambuf      b: 0
google::protobuf::io::OstreamOutputStream raw_output: 8192
google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream coded_output: 13


Buffer conditions after after async write
boost::asio::streambuf      b: 0
google::protobuf::io::OstreamOutputStream raw_output: 8192
google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream coded_output: 13

 bytes_trransferred: 0
```

I have no idea how to do it in a proper way.
OS is RHEL 6.4.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with asio, but it looks to me like the problem is that you aren't flushing your buffers.  The data is stuck in `CodedOutputStream` and never finds its way into asio.

`CodedOutputStream` should be allocated on the stack, such that it is destroyed as soon as you're done writing the message.  The destructor will flush the buffer.  Note that `CodedOutputStream` is cheap to allocate so there's no performance problem with putting it on the stack (in fact, it's probably better that way).

`OstreamOutputStream` can similarly be allocated on the stack, but it heap-allocates a buffer which you might want to reuse.  If you choose to reuse the same object, make sure to call `Flush()` to flush the buffer after the `CodedOutputStream` is destroyed.

Incidentally, `OstreamOutputStream` is not particularly efficient, because it has to do its own layer of buffering on top of what `ostream` is already doing.  You may want to serialize to a string (`str = message.SerializeAsString()` or `message.SerializeToString(&str)`) and then write that directly to the socket (if asio allows this), as it will probably avoid a redundant copy.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Honestly, I could not imagine such behavior of the buffers, so I will try to go the way you offer and place 'em directly into functions. Unfortunatly, I have no idea how to use both `SerializeToString(...)` function and numerical (`varint` in Google's terminology) prefix containing the message's length, as it is prescribed in [Techniques](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#streaming), because the latter should be serialised too.

Comment: Ah, good point.  It's a little complicated.  Basically what you have to do is figure out the size of the message first, then allocate a char array to serialize into, then create a CodedOutputStream that writes directly into that array rather than a ZeroCopyOutputStream.  CodedOutputStream has static methods for determining the size of varints, so you'd add that to the message's `ByteSize()`.  This is all getting a bit ugly, so I'd only do it if you think performance is a big deal.