# How to parse HTTP message from another node to a gRPC server

Tags: c++, http, grpc, grpc-web

I could successfully run a `gRPC client` and `gRPC server` in `c++` now I wish to establish a communication between node A and gRPC server i.e. `node B` as in the attached image.

Are there any examples which I can refer to below is what I am looking for.

I have this node `A` with `http` message (GET method) which I need to parse i.e extract the message and run the request on node C. What is that I should look for in between Node A and gRPC server.

Thanks in Advance

[image: http message to gRPC server]

Comment: I am exploring `grpc-gateway` to act as `reverse-proxy` but IDL and proto file is taking too much time. Appreciate if someone can help me with a better approach or solution.

Comment: It looks like Node A is non gRPC client, i think you may need write a custom adapter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the times, if you have to use HTTP to contact a gRPC node, it most likely means that A is in fact a browser or browser-like environment, since you can simply instantiate a gRPC client on pretty much anything else.

If that's your situation, then I'd suggest having a look at [grpc-web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web) which aims to address that specific situation.

Comment: Hi Frank, appreciate your answer would be happy to accept the answer but if you could please help me with an example where I can use my existing c++ greeter_server to read this http message from HTTP client. Or how that can be done

Comment: If you want to keep the format of the http message as is, then you will have to write logic to interpret it and manually populate a peotobuf. I can't really give you more details than that since I don't know what the message looks like.

Comment: I accept your answer @Mark will get back when I get the format of mesage. Thanks a lot