# Is it possible to implement 'FileInputStream::BackUp()'-like functionality with Varint32 size-prefixed Protocol Buffer messages?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am trying to parse delimited protobuf messages (from a file) in C++ using the [following implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22927149/3813662) of `readDelimitedFrom()` - also copied below:

```
bool readDelimitedFrom(
    google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyInputStream* rawInput,
    google::protobuf::MessageLite* message) {
  // We create a new coded stream for each message.  Don't worry, this is fast,
  // and it makes sure the 64MB total size limit is imposed per-message rather
  // than on the whole stream.  (See the CodedInputStream interface for more
  // info on this limit.)
  google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream input(rawInput);

  // Read the size.
  uint32_t size;
  if (!input.ReadVarint32(&size)) return false;

  // Tell the stream not to read beyond that size.
  google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::Limit limit =
      input.PushLimit(size);

  // Parse the message.
  if (!message->MergeFromCodedStream(&input)) return false;
  if (!input.ConsumedEntireMessage()) return false;

  // Release the limit.
  input.PopLimit(limit);

  return true;
}
```

My issue is that I need to group messages and process them in batches based on a `uint32_t` field contained within the message - let's call it `id`.

Currently, I have the following code in my main loop:

```
...
int infd = -1;
_sopen_s(&infd, argv[1], _O_RDONLY | _O_BINARY, _SH_DENYWR, _S_IREAD);

google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyInputStream *input = 
    new google::protobuf::io::FileInputStream(infd);

std::vector<ProtoMessage> msgList;
bool readMore = true;

do {
    ProtoMessage msg;
    readMore = readNextMessage(input, msg, msgList);

    if (!msgList.empty()) {
        std::cout << "Processing Message Batch - ID: " << msgList[0].id();
        /* some processing done here */
    }
} while (readMore);
```

The implementation of `readNextMessage()` is as follows:

```
bool readNextMessage(
    google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyInputStream* rawInput,
    ProtoMessage& nextMsg,
    std::vector<ProtoMessage>& batchList) {

    bool sameBatch = false;
    uint32_t msgID = 0;
    do {
        if (readDelimitedFrom(rawInput, &scan) == -1)
            return false;
        if (nextMsg.id() == 0)
            msgID = nextMsg.id();    // guaranteed to be non-zero
        if (sameBatch = (msgID == nextMsg.id()))
            batchList.push_back(nextMsg); 
    } while (sameBatch); 

    // need a way to roll-back here as nextMsg is now the first new
    // ProtoMessage belonging to a new batch.

    return true;
}
```

The logic of this function is fairly simple: take a `ZeroCopyInputStream` and parse it using `readDelimitedFrom()` to group `ProtoMessage` messages into a vector based on their `id` field. If it encounters a message with a new id, stop and return control back to `main` for processing on the message batch.

This leads to the undesired requirement of having to consume/read the first message (including its Varint32-encoded size) that *does not* belong to the previous batch without having a way to 'backup' the stream. I would like to be able to point the `ZeroCopyInputStream` to the location before the last `readDelimitedFrom()`.

Is there any way for me to modify `readDelimitedFrom()` to also return the number of bytes consumed during its call, and then use pointer arithmetic on the `ZeroCopyInputStream` to achieve the desired functionality?

The provided function `ZeroCopyInputStream::Backup()` has a precondition that `ZeroCopyInputStream::Next()` be the last method call. Obviously, this is not the case when using the `CodedInputStream` wrapper to parse delimited messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ZeroCopyInputStream::Backup()` can only back up over the last *buffer* received. A single message may span multiple buffers, therefore there's no general way to do what you want given the `ZeroCopyInputStream` interface.

Some options:

- Call `rawInput->ByteCount()` before parsing each message, in order to determine exactly the byte position where the message started. If you need to roll back, seek the underlying file backwards and recreate the `ZeroCopyInputStream` on top of it. This only works if you are reading from a file, of course.
- When you encounter a message in a new batch, store it off to the side, and then bring it back out when the caller asks to start reading the next batch.

Comment: Thanks Kenton - I figured this was the case. I'm currently doing the second option you mentioned.


So I guess whatever a `ZeroCopyInputStream` has read in the past is not accessible anymore? As in, we need to seek its underlying file and re-create as opposed to dealing with the same `ZeroCopyInputStream`?

Comment: @KnightsValour Yes, basically.