# Is it possible to get the true read position of a StreamReader relative to its underlying stream?

Tags: c#, performance

Alternatively, is it possible to tell a [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to reset the position of its underlying stream to the first unconsumed byte, after which `BaseStream.Position` would have the desired value?

This is important because there's a lot of stuff that only the stream reader knows about. That's not only the actual parsing position within a line, but also things like line endings of different lengths and byte order marks.

[`DiscardBufferedData()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.discardbuffereddata%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) fails to reset the underlying stream to the correct position, so no dice there.

Background: `StreamReader` uses internal buffering, which means that `BaseStream.Position` is out of sync and only tells where the currently buffered block ends. For diagnostic purposes it would by useful to include the actual byte offset in a message, especially with files that are hundreds of megabytes in size. With a byte offset it would be possible to go directly to the indicated position, as opposed to having to scan the whole file in order to count line endings (when only a line number is given).

There are other potential uses for the byte offset, like handing off processing from the stream reader to code that does raw reads via the base stream. That would allow it to keep using the stream reader for all parts that are not performance-critical and to limit raw byte processing to those parts where it matters.

And matter it can sometimes, with speedups to the tune of orders of magnitude... For example, in code challenges like SPOJ's like [INTEST - Enormous Input Test](http://www.spoj.com/problems/INTEST/) and lots of other tasks, where the CLR's native input/output can be orders of magnitude slower than the actual algorithm for crunching the numbers and hence can needlessly cause time limits to be exceeded.

Comment: I've had this issue with other streams that buffer (protobuf's `CodedInputStream`). The problem is that the original stream is effectively owned by the encompassing stream/reader and you shouldn't be messing with it anymore. I don't think you can do anything about it without making your own reader.

Comment: True enough, which is why I was looking for an officially sanctioned way (much like [Microsoft's official explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.discardbuffereddata%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of the interaction between StreamReader and seeks on the underlying stream).

Comment: Perhaps you can, I'm betting you can't because you don't own the original stream anymore, the reader does. here is my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33733913/why-does-codedinputstream-set-stream-position-to-end

Comment: I assume you have used a decompiler on the class already. I just did and I did not find a way to do it (except of course private reflection). An idea of mine was to write a wrapper encoding as a way to hook StreamReader's internals but it turns out that decoded chars are buffered as well.

Comment: Another idea would be to have a wrapper stream return bytes in chunks of 1. That destroys perf and it's not guaranteed to work in the future.