# Communication from Java to C++ using ProtoBuf over socket

Tags: java, c++, sockets, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to send an message from Java client to C++ server using ProtoBuf over socket. My program hangs while i am trying to create InputStream. Thanks in advance if some one could help me on this and here is my part of client code in java:

```
String host = "xxxxxxxxx";
int port = xxxx;

Builder builder = CarSelection.Car.newBuilder();
builder.setLabel("Audi");
builder.setValue("A6");

Car car = builder.build();
Socket client = new Socket(host, port);

byte[] result = car.toByteArray() ;  
car.writeDelimitedTo(client.getOutputStream());

Car recieveData= car.parseDelimitedFrom(client.getInputStream());
```

It is able to write to output stream but my program hangs when trying to read from input stream.

Comment: Are you trying to read and write from the _same_ application?  From Java at both ends?

Comment: What happens in `writeDelimitedTo` and `parseDelimitedFrom`?

Comment: the other end is written in C++, i am trying to write a java client to get the data from c++

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340730/are-there-c-equivalents-for-the-protocol-buffers-delimited-i-o-functions-in-ja/